# How to format java.util.Date to a date in "MM/dd/yyyy" format in ruby?

Tags: java, ruby

I want to convert a Java object to be formatted in ruby.

I used the following code

```
def format_date(date,date_format)
    return Date::strptime(date, date_format)
end
```

date is an instance of java.util.Date
date_format = "%d/%m/%Y"

I am getting the following error in ruby

```
private method `sub!' called for #<Java::JavaUtil::Date:0x150ea09>
```

Answer (score 2):

convert to JRuby Time and use strftime like this:

```
def format_date(date, date_format)
    t = Time.at(date.time/1000)
    return t.strftime(date_format)
end
```

Java Date time Method gives the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, Ruby Time number of seconds since that time.